# How to create a look with last 3 weeks of year over same period last year in Looker?

Tags: week-number, looker

I am a newbie in Looker and am having issues creating a look that will return information for a metric from the last 3 weeks this year and the same period last year.

Currently, I am able to get the data for every week this year and last year. I am using `Week num` and pivot by `Year`. The thing I am struggling with is how to implement a filter that will return solely the last 3 weeks. I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.looker.com/exploring-data/creating-looker-expressions/looker-functions-and-operators?version=6.24)  but am not sure how to implement it as under the Date Functions there is no function for week or week number.

Below you can find an example of my what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doing a period analysis for the last 3 weeks, *i.e. last trailing 3 weeks* from `now()` as well as the 3 trailing weeks from the previous year (week-of-year, over week-of-year), I would do this:

**Use a date filter as well as a conditional, custom filter.**

> For my example, I'm using "end at week of year" dimensions for your measure "Metric A".

- Be aware this solution does not cutoff the week-of-year to the last 3 in the data table, but I used a filter `is not null` to hide measures from future weeks in our current year.

  - My "end at week of year" dimension is a number, not a date/time type in my particular explore, so I am not able to use the relative date filter expressions on it.

Screenshot:

[My Filters for past 2 years and excluding null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn489.png)

I also added this custom filter using a dimension in my explore that is a `time` type, [so I could use the **extract** function](https://discourse.looker.com/t/using-dates-in-table-calculations-3-30/1398):

Conditions:

1. Is the month smaller than current month, if true we'll include in
   the count
2. Check for records within the same month as the current month, if it is the same day of the month or earlier, we'll include

```
extract_months(${getaround_trip.time_end_at_week}) < extract_months(now()) OR
extract_months(${getaround_trip.time_end_at_week}) = extract_months(now()) AND
extract_days(${getaround_trip.time_end_at_week}) <= extract_days(now())
```

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCTbW.png)
*You could apply a formating to the table, to only show the first 3 rows of the table if you were adding it to a dashboard.*

Also, be aware of how you define your first day of the week - [Here is link to documentation](https://docs.looker.com/reference/model-params/week_start_day) for `week_start_day` from Looker; it accepts any day of the week, but the default is Monday.